# RC low pass filter on MOSFET gate

Tags: mosfet, filter

I have to supply the gate of a mosfet with a Vgs PWM voltage.

I had thought of directly connecting the GPIO [0 .. 5]V output of the microcontroller to the gate and putting a resistor on the gate (between GPIO and gate), knowing that the voltage 'seen' by the gate would be *Vgs = DutyCycle x 5V* ... but is such a connection correct?
Are we sure that the gate sees a Vgs=DutyCycle*5V ??
Wouldn't it start switching ?? (regardless of duty cycle)

Maybe I need an RC filter (between GPIO and the gate of the mosfet) to achieve what I described.
If I'm right .. can you explain why I need a RC filter ??

Comment: Your opening line says this: *I have to supply the gate of a mosfet with a Vgs PWM voltage.* <-- that says it all basically so, why are you debating about an RC filter?

Comment: Are you trying to operate the MOSFET in the linear region, or do you want it to switch on and off with your PWM signal?

Comment: It's very common to switch the MOSFET fully on, fully off, with the PWM signal, and put any smoothing required on the output side of the MOSFET.  But it does depend on what you are driving with the MOSFET.

Comment: @evildemonic I want to control the current on the drain by modifying a PWM the Vgs of the msofet

Comment: @Andyaka my teacher said that by connecting PWM to the gate I will not have Vgs = DutyCycle x 5V ... I have to use an RC low-pass filter to make this formula "true" (in this application case)

Comment: That contradicts your opening line.

Comment: Your teacher is correct...unless the gate capacitance is huge, your frequency is very high, and that combined with your source resistance itself forms the low-pass filter.

Comment: @evildemonic If I simply put a resistor on the gate (330 ohms) ... I have a low-pass filter formed by that 330 ohm and the parasitic capacitance Cgs (e.g. 1nF) forming a cutoff frequency = 1/2pi*330*1nF = 482kHz
What would be the problem?
I feed the mosfet with PWM at 1kHz .. so I have no problem :/
In my opinion the only problem is that with 482kHz any disturbances at high frequencies also pass through .. am I wrong?

Comment: That is exactly your problem.  Your low pass filter's cutoff frequency is so high as to be useless for its intended purpose.

Comment: "I want to control the current on the drain by modifying a PWM the Vgs of the msofet" If that is true, you need to filter the PWM signal before the MOSFET.  If the PWM frequency is 1kHz, a low-pass with a cutoff 400+ times that can't help...it won't be filtering the PWM at all.

Comment: @evildemonic Thank you very much for your reply. Sorry again if I insist, now I understand the question of the RC cut-off frequency to filter 1kHz .. but I think I still don't understand "why I have to filter". Maybe because without proper filtering the PWM voltage won't get through? Why?
What happens to the PWM signal at the gate if it is not filtered correctly?
Thanks!

Comment: Because what you want is a slowly varying voltage at the gate, not pulses from the PWM.  You want the PWM to be smoothed out to more like a wave shape.  You are trying to vary the voltage at the gate to affect current through the source/drain in a smooth way, not switch it fully on and off rapidly. See if this helps:  https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/low-pass-filter-a-pwm-signal-into-an-analog-voltage/